# Lucene: How to get real-time index information during indexing? (Index size and term count)

Tags: java, lucene

I want to get information about Lucene's index in a real-time manner during the indexing process. So I use CheckIndex class in my code, as follows:

```
CheckIndex.Status indexStatus = checkIndex.checkIndex();
Iterator<CheckIndex.Status.SegmentInfoStatus> iterator = indexStatus.segmentInfos.iterator();
CheckIndex.Status.SegmentInfoStatus temp = null;
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    temp = iterator.next();
    term_number += temp.termIndexStatus.termCount;
    index_MB_size += temp.sizeMB;
}
```

At first, the index folder is empty. I output `term_number` and `index_MB_size` each time when Lucene finishes indexing a text file(about 10MB each, all about 600MB). So I get about 60 pairs of result. But I am sad to find that the 2 variables in 60 pairs are always 0. Only when the index segment is finished, the statistical information will show a non-zero result.

I guess this is caused by the fact that the CheckIndex class can only work correctly after indexing is finished. But I haven't checked.

How can I get the information in a real-time manner? In addition, the CheckIndex process is really time-consuming, is there any other better way to get the two aspects of information (index size and term number)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the answer in the book ***Lucene In Action 2nd Edition***.

It is because that `IndexReader` and `CheckIndex` can only see the changes to the index after the `commit()` method has been called by the `IndexWriter`. *Commit* is very different from *Flush*, since *flush* only flush all the buffered data to the disk, while `Commit` will do *flush* first and then make all the changes visible to `IndexReader`.